# eclipse - how to deploy folder into tomcat war

Tags: eclipse, tomcat7, eclipse-indigo

I used to work with an old version of eclipse and tomcat several years ago. And I remember that there was a configuration option that said what folders will be deployed to tomcat war, besides the compiled source folder. For example, copy a folder with JS files

However, I cannot find this option in eclipse-indigo. Could you help please?

Comment: Why aren't you using Juno SR2?

Comment: I can switch to Juno if I discover how to configure it there